# Scala Cake Pattern: Splitting large components into separate files

Tags: scala, cake-pattern

I'd like to use the Cake Pattern for splitting parts of some software system into components to make it completely modular as proposed in [this article](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/ScalableComponent.pdf). In the simplest case I'd like to have some mockable components, let's say Logging, Config, Database, Scripts etc which could potentially use each other. The code might look like

```
trait AbstractConfig {
  def config: AbstractConfigInterface
  trait AbstractConfigInterface {
    def test: Unit
  }
}

trait SomeConfig extends AbstractConfig {
  this: Core =>  
  def config = SomeConfigImplementation
  object SomeConfigImplementation extends AbstractConfigInterface {
    def test = println("conf.test method called")
  }
}

trait AbstractDatabase {
  def database: AbstractDatabaseInterface
  trait AbstractDatabaseInterface {
    def connect: Unit
  }
}

trait SomeDatabase extends AbstractDatabase {
  this: Core =>
  def database = SomeDatabaseImplementation
  object SomeDatabaseImplementation extends AbstractDatabaseInterface {
    def connect = {
      println("connect method called")
      core.conf.test
    }
  }
}

trait Core {
  this: AbstractDatabase with AbstractConfig =>
  def core = CoreInterface
  object CoreInterface {
    def db = database
    def conf = config
  }
}

object app extends Core with SomeDatabase with SomeConfig

object Run {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    app.core.db.connect
  }
}
```

Here the database and config components (`SomeConfig` and `SomeDatabase` traits) are pluggable and can be changed to some other implementations if ever needed. Their implementations have access to `core` object which holds both database and config, so the database can access config if needed and vice versa.

So the question is: If ever some trait like `SomeDatabase` becomes large and doesn't fit into a single file how to split it into separate classes retaining access to the `core` object? To be more specific, let's say I need to move some code out of connect method in `SomeDatabase` to another file:

```
// SomeDatabase.scala
trait SomeDatabase extends AbstractDatabase {
  this: Core =>
  def database = SomeDatabaseImplementation
  object SomeDatabaseImplementation extends AbstractDatabaseInterface {
    def connect = {
      val obj = new SomeClass()
    }
  }
}

// SomeClass.scala in the same package
class SomeClass {
    core.conf.test // Does not compile - how to make it work??
}
```

`SomeClass` is implementation details of how SomeDatabase works, so I obviously wouldn't like to make it a trait and mix it in to application. Is there any way to provide access to `core` object for `SomeClass`?

---

Some related links:

1. [Dependency Injection vs Cake Pattern by Jan Machacek](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2011/12/15/dependency-injection-vs-cake-pattern/)
2. [Real World Scala: Dependency Injection by Jonas Boner](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/)
3. [Dependency Injection in Scala: Extending the Cake Pattern by Adam Warsky](http://www.warski.org/blog/2010/12/di-in-scala-cake-pattern/)
4. [Scalable Component Abstractions by Martin Odersky & Matthias Zenger](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/ScalableComponent.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to pass `Core` in as a constructor parameter to `SomeClass`.

```
// SomeDatabase.scala
trait SomeDatabase extends AbstractDatabase {
  this: Core =>
  def database = SomeDatabaseImplementation
  object SomeDatabaseImplementation extends AbstractDatabaseInterface {
    def connect = {
      val obj = new SomeClass(SomeDatabase.this) // pass it here
    }
  }
}

// SomeClass.scala in the same package
class SomeClass(coreComp: Core) { // use it here
    coreComp.core.conf.test
}
```

Interestingly, I really just wanted to pass `CoreInterface` or `AbstractConfigInterface`, but the fact that they are inner types really made that difficult.

Comment: Dave, thanks for the answer. So far it seems to be the only reasonable way. The only thing I don't dig about it is the necessity to type `coreComp.` in each invocation of any core method. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an option to work with `CoreInterface` directly, does it?

Comment: You can `import coreComp._` to reduce the typing.